# NodeJS Streaming Response

Tags: node.js, error-handling, streaming, fetch-api, http2

The background: My API is reaching out to a streaming endpoint on another server that I don't control (details not super important here). As the stream comes in, I'm proxying the streamed chunks to the browser. The browser reaches out to my API via `Fetch` + an async iterable

The problem: The streaming endpoint I'm proxying isn't guaranteed to maintain a successful connection or be free from errors (it can time out, downstream calls on its side can fail, etc.)

The question: What is the best way to signal the front-end that an error occurred mid-stream. I thought of sending a serialized error as JSON in the final chunk before closing the connection, but I find this solution a bit hackish and was wondering if there's a better way to do this. Preferably, something that follows standard conventions.

Example of a possible approach which I'm not especially fond of:

```
let myStreamResponse: AxiosResponse<NodeJS.ReadableStream>;
let myStream: NodeJS.ReadableStream;

try {
  myStreamResponse = await streamingClient.streamSomeStuff(payload);
  myStream = chatStreamResponse.data;
} catch (error) {
  return res.status(500).send('It isnt working man');
}

myStream.on('error', (error) => {
  const streamError = new MyStreamError('Something broke');
  errorTransport.error(streamError);
  res.write(serializeError(streamError)));

  return res.end();
});

// Etc, etc.
```